# How to migrate only wordpress theme from localhost to live server

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently working on a project, actually we an online site, we are thinking of revamping this, on this online site we have many blogs already,

We have purchased a theme also and doing many customization on localhost.

How is this possible to update the theme with customization and pages on `online server` from `localhost` without affecting the blog posts ??

Comment: Just copy&paste your themes folder

Comment: that will only copy the themes, If I have created any post or page or any widget, then it should also go to online

Comment: You said `without affecting blog posts`, but want to insert new posts?

Comment: SO older blog post should remain same and can add new post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK these are the steps that i do for putting site from local to live.

1. First move full wordpress site including all wp-admin,wp-content,wp-includes and files to you live server
2. then export you local server database
3. and this is the trick, open the .sql in a text editor like dreamweaver then replace all links like `http://localhost/site to http://www.livesite.com`
4. and now move or import this db to live server and apply settings in wp-config.php.

it always works for me.

Comment: and whats about my older blog post on live site ?

Comment: @lord_linus both db are different? i suggest make your local site fully functional and move it to live.